# kafka connect to minio

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, minio

please what are the correct steps to  connect kafka with minio for i can ingest data from kafka to minio

i installed Amazon S3 Sink Connector but i don't know how to configure it with minio
this is the problem that i have :

```
[2024-03-22 13:44:22,766] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli:100)org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unable to initialize REST serverat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeServer(RestServer.java:199)at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.startConnect(AbstractConnectCli.java:129)at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.run(AbstractConnectCli.java:94)at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:182)Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8083at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeServer(RestServer.java:197)... 3 moreCaused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in useat java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)at 
java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)... 10 more
```

Comment: The error is not specific to Minio, but please share all relevant configs and commands you've used. The error says you're already running something on port 8083. Perhaps another kafka connect process?